# Jenkins parameters from property file based on global env vars

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, extended-choice-parameter

**Context:**

input parameters to jenkins job are defined in a property file. property file location changes based on environment in which jenkins is running

ex: for *dev* environment path be like `/app/dev/some/nested/path/propertyfile`

for *prod* environment path be like `/app/prod/some/nested/path/propertyfile`

presently using **extended choice parameter plugin** to read property file. this works well if path to property file is absolute.

**Problem:**

is there a way to include global env variable in property file path?
can it be done using **active-choices plugin**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**using active-choices plugin**

```
def choices=[]
textFile= new File("/app/${Gloabl_Var}/some/nested/path/propertyfile")
textFile.eachLine{ line ->
if(line.startsWith('<Property-Key-Name>')) {
 line.split('=')[1].split(',').each {
choices.add(it)
}}}
return choices
```

**using extended choice parameter plugin**

can't use property file directly, will need to use groovy script

```
import hudson.slaves.EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty
import jenkins.model.Jenkins
def global_env_var=Jenkins.get().globalNodeProperties.get(EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty.class).envVars['<Global_Var>']
def props = new Properties()
def stream = new FileInputStream("/app/${global_env_var}/some/nested/path/propertyfile")
try {
props.load(stream)
} finally {
stream.close()
}
return props.getProperty('<Property-Key-Name>').split(',')
```

References:

[extended-choice](https://sathishpk.wordpress.com/2016/03/07/jenkinsgroovyactivechoiceparameter-rendering-dynamic-parameter-by-reading-only-keys-from-property-file/)

[active-choices](https://groups.google.com/g/jenkinsci-users/c/tzvYEp76IVg)